# Is it possible to change the tick count value returned from GetTickCount()?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to do some testing and it requires the Windows system to be up and running for 15 Real-Time minutes before a certain action can ever occur. However, this is very time consuming to HAVE to wait the 15 real-time minutes.

Is there a way to change the value GetTickCount() returns so as to make it appear that the system has been running for 15 real-time minutes?

Edit: There is an app that does something close to what I want, but it doesn't quite seem to work and I have to deal with hexadecimal values instead of straight decimal values: http://ysgyfarnog.co.uk/utilities/AdjustTickCount/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly.

Why not just mock the call, or replace the chunk of code that does the time check with a strategy object?

```
struct Waiter
{
    virtual void Wait() = 0;
    virtual ~Waiter() {};
};

struct 15MinWaiter : public Waiter
{
    virtual void Wait()
    {
        //Do something that waits for 15 mins
    }
};

struct NothingWaiter : public Waiter
{
    virtual void Wait()
    {
        //Nill
    } 
};
```

You could do similar to mock out a call to GetTickCount, but doing this at the higher level of abstraction of whatever is doing the wait is probably better.

Comment: Yeah ... that would be ideal. However, I'm not the developer and don't have access to change the code. I was hoping to do this externally. I guess I could try to make a case for the developer to make this adjustable so during testing I can choose to not wait.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the time ahead on the test machine after starting the app? I don't know if this affects the value returned by GetTickCount() but it would be easy to test.

Comment: No, the system clock has nothing to do with GetTickCount() unfortunately ... it just stores a value for the number of milliseconds since the system started and increments it as time goes by. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging purposes, you can just replace all the calls to GetTickCount() with _GetTickCount(), which can implement to return with GetTickCount() or GetTickCount()+15min, depending whether or not you are debugging.

Why not make it one minute, confirm it works, then change it back to fifteen?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something quite hideous like #define GetTickCount() MyReallyEvilReplacement().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application Verifier provided with the Windows SDK to run your app with the "Miscellaneous > TimeRollOver" test. It will fake a tick count which starts at a time that will overflow after a short moment.

Another possibility is to to hibernate / hybrid shutdown / sleep a Windows system, then boot to the BIOS, change the date time to something you require, like add 30 days if you want to test unsigned tick counts. When Windows boots again, it has no way of detecting the appropiate time since the computer really started previously, and thinks it is running for 30 more days. It is important to use sleep / hibernate / hybrid shutdown (the latter being the default since Windows 8), not a full shutdown, as the up time is otherwise reset.

Yet another possibility could be to hook imports of GetTickCount to your own code and let it return arbitrary results.